# Adding an array of objects to a useState hook

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm looking to find a way to add an array of objects to a useState hook. My approach works with an array of strings but not with an array of objects

```
const [info, setInfo] = useState([{}])

let names = [{name: "george"}, {name: "bill"}, {name: "adam"}]

setInfo((oldArray) =>  [...oldArray, names])
```

Comment: Is this what you need? `setInfo((oldArray) =>  [...oldArray, ...names])`

Comment: Also, as a general advice, it would be great to get more info. i.e. - what is the expected output, what are you currently receiving, etc.. (even if it seems obvious)

Comment: just change your first line like this `const [info, setInfo] = useState([])` and remove {}

Comment: Have you also looked into useReducer? It might be more appropriate in your case.  https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer

Answer (score 0):

You have to deconstruct `names` too.

you are currently setInfo like

`[{},[{name: "george"}, {name: "bill"}, {name: "adam"}]]`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve the issue by adding a spread operator for names as well

```
setInfo((oldArray) =>  [...oldArray, ...names])
```